# Problem with beamer documentclass: xcolor.sty not found

Tags: beamer, color

I am trying to run the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{%
\usetheme[hideothersubsections,
right,width=22mm]{Goettingen}
}
\title{Simple Presentation}
\author[D. Flipo]{Daniel Flipo}
\institute{U.S.T.L. \& GUTenberg}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{USTL}}
\date{2005}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{An Example}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Things to do on a Sunday Afternoon}
\begin{block}{One could \ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item walk the dog\dots \pause
\item read a book\pause
\item confuse a cat\pause
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
and many other things
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
xcolor.sty not found
```

I have also tried

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

in the preamble of the document with and without options like `dvips` and `svgnames` but I cannot get rid of the error

```
xcolor.sty not found
```

I run the code by pressing 'PDFLaTeX' on LED and am using MiKTeX 2.9 distribution.

Comment: Welcome! I’d recommend to enable on-the-fly installation in the MiKTeX settings. If you don’t want to do that, you could also go into the package manager and install the package from there.

Comment: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: @doncherry, I have on-the-fly installation already enabled. I successfully updated tex distribution with and without admin. I was not able to install installable packages though via package manger. It shows the following error after after downloading the packages:
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:

C:\Users\ASHISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mikA558.tmp
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageInstaller.cpp
Line: 3285
MiKTeX: 2.9

Comment: @user30850 Hmm .. I sort of guessing here, but since it’s a temporary file, I’d delete that file and try again. And make sure you’re using a good, up-do-date MiKTeX mirror server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MikTeX tree this package may be located here:
`\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty`.
If not, please download `xcolor.sty` and put it into your working directory or, better, the whole package `xcolor`, using MikTeX tools of updating.